# Symfony 2.6: Collection as Form

Tags: symfony

i have an array with entities. I know that symfony has a [collection type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html), but that what i want doesn't work as intended. I have created a FormType for a single entity and a FormType for the collection (formtype code for the collection):

```
$builder
            ->add('list', 'collection', array(
                'label' => 'list',
                'type' => new SingleItemType(),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ));
```

Now i have tried to create a Form

```
$arr = array(new Item(), new Item(), new Item());
$this->createForm(new CollectionListType(), $arr);
```

But this doesn't work; I get an error which means i should set "Item" as data_class, if i do this, an another error appears which means i should set data_class to null.

Another approach was to create a dummy entity which holds my array of Item-Entities but this doesn't works too.

Is there a simple approach to display a list of entities as collection form?

Greetings

Comment: Have you tried this cookbook entry, [how to embed a collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure totally understand your problem but I think you must create first an Entity with getList()/setList(). In your collection field, you can add a new "default" entity passing a value to "data" key in option array.

Comment: Jep. This is the only working way. I have hoped i can passed directly an array to the form builder like array('list' => array(new Item(), new Item() ..)); but only strange errors appears.